# Reading zip files without full download

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, zip

Is it possible to read the contents of a .ZIP file without fully downloading it?

I'm building a crawler and I'd rather not have to download every zip file just to index their contents.

Thanks;

Comment: It should be possible to fetch only the file's header and table of contents. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29#File_headers

Comment: What do you mean by "read the contents"? Do you mean just the list of file names of the compressed files?

Comment: Yeah, I only need the filenames. The contents per se aren't relevant to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tricky part is in identifying the start of the central directory, which occurs at the end of the file. Since each entry is the same fixed size, you can do a kind of binary search starting from the end of the file. The binary search is trying to guess how many entries are in the central directory. Start with some reasonable value, N, and retrieve that portion of the file at end-(N*sizeof(DirectoryEntry)). If that file position does not start with the central directory entry signature, then N is too large - half and repeat, otherwise, N is too small, double and repeat. Like binary search, the process maintains the current upper and lower bound. When the two become equal, you've found the value for N, the number of entries.

The number of times you hit the webserver, is at most 16, since there can be no more than 64K entries.

Whether this is more efficient than downloading the whole file depends on the file size. You might request the size of the resource before downloading, and if it's smaller than a given threshold, download the entire resource. For large resources, requesting multiple offsets will be quicker, and overall less taxing for the webserver, if the threshold is set high.

HTTP/1.1 allows ranges of a resource to be downloaded. For HTTP/1.0 you have no choice but to download the whole file.

Comment: @Earlz - The HTTP/1.1 resource ranges is the backbone of downloaders and interruptable/pausable downloads. See 14.36 Range in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt

Answer (score 4):

the [format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) suggests that the key piece of information about what's in the file resides at the end of it.  Entries are then specified as an offset from that particular entry, so you'll need to have access to the whole thing I believe.

GZip formats are able to be read as a stream I believe.

Comment: Yes, zip headers are at the end. You need the whole file _OR_ a downloader that lets you get specific parts.

Comment: GZip can be read as a stream, but all it is is a compressed stream.  gzip doesn't have any type of container or multiple files, that's why `.tar.gz` is used:  `.tar` combines files and `.gz` compresses them.

Comment: it's more like a footer then.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. All you need is server that allows to read bytes in ranges, fetch end recored (to know size of CD), fetch central directory (to know where file starts and ends) and then fetch proper bytes and handle them.

Here is implementation in pyhon: [onlinezip](https://github.com/kgonia/onlinezip)

[full disclosure: I'm author of library]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution implemented in ArchView
"ArchView can open archive file online without downloading the whole archive."
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5028/

Inside the archview-0.7.1.xpi in the file "archview.js" you can look at their javascript approach.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this helps, as I'm not a programmer. But in Outlook you can preview zip files and see the actual content, not just the file directory (if they are previewable documents like a pdf).